# func setupSession() { session = AVCaptureSession() session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera

I just started learning Swift and following some sample codes that people have developed. One of them is a camera app. However, no single code worked for me in the past. Please see one example below by mawnch. 
When I run it, I got an error message

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'session'"

```
func setupSession() {
  session = AVCaptureSession()   
  session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Swift Syntax below, Initialize `session` as global variable for particular file,

```
var session: AVCaptureSession!
```

and use below method,

```
func setupSession() {
    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = .photo
}
```

Let me know in case of any queries.